# Converting Avro GenericData.Record to Bytes Array failed

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro

I created GenericData.Record from POJO class in Java ,
and trying to serialize this object to bytes array and send it to kafka topic , 
using the attached code.
But i'm getting the following exception:
UserMetaData cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.generic.IndexedRecord

What is wrong?

Thanks!

```
@Override
public byte[] serialize(String topic, T data) {
        try {
        byte[] result = null;

        if (data != null) {
        LOGGER.debug("data='{}'", data);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BinaryEncoder binaryEncoder =
        EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(byteArrayOutputStream, null);

        DatumWriter<GenericRecord> datumWriter = new GenericDatumWriter<>(data.getSchema());
        datumWriter.write(data, binaryEncoder);

        binaryEncoder.flush();
        byteArrayOutputStream.close();

        result = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        LOGGER.debug("serialized data='{}'", DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(result));
        }
        return result;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new SerializationException(
        "Can't serialize data='" + data + "' for topic='" + topic + "'", ex);
        }
        }
```

Comment: Why not use existing Confluent Avro serializers? And I think you should show your UserMetadata class

Comment: Hi , Actually I don't have the schema of GenericData.Record . (avdl / avsc) , I generated it by reflection .  So i'm not sure I can use Confluent Avro serializers

Comment: Latest versions should https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/pull/1111